# how can i return the values from one specific object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am running a JSON server to create a simple login system. The data from the server looks like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "password": "pass1",
      "email": "useer1@user.com",
      "id": 2,
      "details": {
        "first_name": "user1_1",
        "last_name": "user1_2",
        "gender": "male",
        "pic": "",
        "about": "fnbewhbdwie"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "password": "pass2",
      "email": "user2@user.com",
      "details": {
        "first_name": "user2_1",
        "last_name": "user2_2",
        "gender": "male",
        "pic": "",
        "about": "cjkdbvcwvebxcnoewbvcu"
      },
      "id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created a function to check if the name and password match from the user input, and if the condition is true I want to run another function that will return only the details of the object that have the name and password from the user input.

I have tried the find() method but it returns the details for the first object only

```
async getAcc() {
    const {data} = await Axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}users`)
        data.forEach(({name, password}) => {
          if(this.nameInput.value === name && this.passInput.value === password){
            showAcc();
          }
          else {
            return false
          }
        }
      )
  function showAcc() {
    let result = data.find(a => a.details)
    console.log(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not be doing this level of authentication on your client - your current system sends your entire user database to everyone who even opens the login page

Comment: yeah, no pw in cleartext

Comment: This is not for any client.. It's just a personal project to understand data manipulation with react and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside the obvious problem with the user/pwd on the response, as mentioned on comments, I believe that what is wrong here is this:

First, your data is an array of objects. 
So, by definition, 'find' will return the first entry that the lamba function successfully satisfies. In this case, you are passing the array into the find and saying, give me the first details object you find. It is doing the right thing.

I believe that your problem is on the forEach. Since you added name and pwd as parameters , it is only picking those properties for each item on the array. Try and change it to something like

```
.forEach(item => {,
```

which will send into the lamba function the complete object. Then, inside the method you will need to modify and use

```
if(this.nameInput.value === item.name
```

Finally, inside your if statement, you'll be able to even simplify your showAcc by sending the "details" property straight into the method like:

```
showAcc(item.details);
```

and

```
function showAcc(details) {
     console.log(details); 
}
```

Would be better if you had a sample we could edit , but I think this should work.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the lodash filter method instead of find method.

Something like: _.filter(data, { 'name': 'user2', 'password': 'pass2' });

It should get you all the objects that match your criteria passed in the argument object as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

WebDever may have pointed you to a better solution.  I'll just point out my observation, which directly explains why you fail to print all the answers.

I don't know anything about any of the technology used, but it seems that the problem has to be the return value (or lack thereof) of the code block inside the forEach. Just showing the result, it appears, should in and of itself have no side effect in terms of stopping the iteration. So the key thing that happens when you first find a match is that you don't return 'false'. Up to that point, you've always been returning 'false'.

So my guess is that when you find a match, you're returning the result of the last expression rather than 'false', and that return value causes the iteration to stop. So change the code within the foreach to:

```
if(this.nameInput.value === name && this.passInput.value === password){     
    showAcc();
}
return false
```